# Delay in Android Wear putDataItem() and invoking of onDataChanged()

Tags: wear-os, android-wear-data-api, android-wear-notification

I want to use the action button "Open" on a notification on my Android Wear application, to open a Dialog with some task data on my handheld.
 To do this, I put my message in a PutDataMapRequest and use the following method in my Wearable code:

```
PutDataMapRequest dataMap = PutDataMapRequest.create("/task/" + "1");

dataMap.getDataMap().putString(DataMapKeys.TASK_MESSAGE, message);
....
dataMap.getDataMap().putLong("timestamp", System.currentTimeMillis());

PutDataRequest putDataRequest = dataMap.asPutDataRequest();

Wearable.DataApi.putDataItem(googleApiClient, putDataRequest).setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataApi.DataItemResult>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(DataApi.DataItemResult dataItemResult) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Sending task data: " + dataItemResult.getStatus().isSuccess());
    }
});
```

And then, to catch it in my WearableListenerService on my handheld/mobile device:

```
@Override
public void onDataChanged(DataEventBuffer dataEvents) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Received task data, now opening dialog..");
}
```

However, there is a significant delay (about 10 seconds) between the call to `onResult()` in the `putDataItem()` method in my Wear app, and the invoking of the `onDataChanged()` method in my mobile app.
 This means that when I press the "Open" Action button on the notification on my watch, the dialog opens about 10 seconds later on my phone.
 I would like this to be instant, if possible.

**Is this possible, or am I doing something wrong here in my code?**

Best,

Answer (score 1):

Switch to using [`MessageApi`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/wearable/MessageApi). It is intended for situations like this: it doesn't have a guarantee of delivery (if the devices are not connected at the moment), but is fast. And clicking a button is exactly the situation where it should be used (because user can repeat it).